# How can I return a class in enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have a enum called scenes and some classes like game and menu, I get class of the enum using id how can I do that? thats all I need. sorry my english is bad.

EDIT:

this is my code

```java
public enum Scenes {
    
    MENU(1, "Menu"),
    GAME(2, "Game");
    
    public static int Scene = 1;
    
    private int id;
    private String name;
    
    private Scenes (int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please show your code instead of describing it. That will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. Can you please clarify what you mean by "I get class of the enum using id"? Are you asking for a method that returns `MENU` when the input is 1 and `GAME` when the input is 2?

Comment: OK, we see the code of the enum, what are you trying to do? You can refer to MENU and GAME in your code. You probably don't need your explicit id, check out the ordinal() method on a enum if really you need an number instead of the enum.

Comment: I want to get my menu.java from id like Ilya Sazonov answer use a valueOf but it should return my class

Comment: `Scenes.valueOf(Scenes.Scene).render(camera, deltaTime)` something like this

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this? To get Scenes object based on it's id?

```java
Scenes scene = Scenes.valueOf(1)
```

Then that's how you do it. Look at the **valueOf** method.

```java
public enum Scenes {
    
    MENU(1, "Menu"),
    GAME(2, "Game");
    
    public static int Scene = 1;
    
    private int id;
    private String name;
    
    private Scenes (int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static Scenes valueOf(int id) {
        for (Scenes value : Scenes.values()) { 
            if (value.getId() == id) {
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

But pay attention, that calling values() repetitively is bad for performance. So you probably should build **Map<Integer, Scenes>** in static initialization block and save the map to a **static final** field.